# Breaking Threaded Loops within Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a small program to ping multiple IPs at the same time via sending 10 pings. This both records the results within a dict and also prints the status to a page.

However I want to allow the program to ping constantly and for the user to stop it rather then rely on a max ping count.

```
import os
import re
import time
import sys
import subprocess
import Queue
import threading

class pinger:

    def __init__(self,hosts):
        self.q = Queue.Queue()
        self.all_results = []
        self.hosts = hosts

    def send_ping(self,q,ip):
        self.q.put(self.record_results(ip))

    def record_results(self,ip):
        ping_count = 0

        host_results = {
            "host" : ip,
            "device" : None,
            "sent_count" : 0,
            "success_count": 0,
            "fail_count": 0,
            "failed_perc": 0,
            "curr_status": None
        }

        while ping_count < 10:
            rc = subprocess.call(['ping', '-c', '1', '-W', '1', ip], stdout=open('/dev/null', 'w'), stderr=open('/dev/null', 'w'))
            ping_count += 1

            # update stats

            host = host_results['host']
            sent_count = host_results['sent_count']
            success_count = host_results['success_count']
            fail_count = host_results['fail_count']
            failed_perc = host_results['failed_perc']
            curr_status = host_results['curr_status']

            sent_count += 1

            if rc == 0:
                success_count += 1
                curr_status = "Successful Response"
            else:
                fail_count += 1
                curr_status = "Request Timed Out"

            failed_perc =  ( fail_count / sent_count ) * 100

            host_results.update({'failed_perc': failed_perc, 'fail_count': fail_count, 'success_count': success_count, 'curr_status': curr_status, 'sent_count': sent_count})
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print host_results
        self.all_results.append(host_results)
        return True

    def go(self):
        for i in self.hosts:
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.send_ping, args = (self.q,i))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
```

Thanks,

Comment: nothing as yet as im not sure at what part of the code it should really go, and also what you can use an escape sequence

Comment: Do I understand correct that you want to stop the program by `SIGINT` or alike?

Comment: What ever way that would allow me to send the stop request via an AJAX call from the clients browser..

Answer (score 1):

You could change the `while ping_count < 10` condition to `while self.should_ping:` (the variable would be initialized to `True`). Also, if there is a main loop where you wait to gather all the results, you can wrap it with `try: except KeyboardInterrupt:` and set `pinger.should_ping` to `False` in exception handler.

Otherwise, you could register to `SIGINT` signals, as mentioned by @bereal, and set the `should_ping` variable to `False` there.

Comment: `SIGINT` is by default translated into `KeyboardInterrupt` in the main thread as well, so that's the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, As this will later be incorporated with AJAX so that a client can stop the process is there anything else I should know ?

Comment: @bereal, yes but in case there is no clear place where you could place `KeyboardException` handler, the signal handler would seem more appropriate

Comment: @felix001, I guess that you would want many people to use this feature at the same time. This could lead to enormous amount of threads and network traffic. Instead of this, I would suggest a `ThreadPool` or a distributed queue like `Celery`